# Usar parámetro non-type en una plantilla de variable C++

Tags: c++

He aprendido un poco sobre variable-template pero con el parámetro `template <class T>` y ahora quiero lograrlo pero con `template <int T>`, todos los intentos me han fallado en la compilación:

```
#include <iostream>

//variable template non-type parameter
template <int T>
double var<T>;


int main(){
    
    //construyo varias instancias
    var<1> = 323.243;
    var<2> = 12.23;
    
    //hago uso de las instancias
    std::cout << var<1> << std::endl;
    std::cout << var<2> << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

El error de compilación aparece en la declaración de la variable pero no me queda claro como arreglar la sintaxis.

Answer (score 2):

No estás usando la sintaxis correcta.

Primero, tenemos que declarar la plantilla:

```
template< int > double var;
```

En tu caso, solo quieres especializaciones, que tenemos que hacer en el mismo *namespace* en el que hicimos la declaración:

```
template< > double var< 1 > = 2332.243;
template< > double var< 2 > = 12.23;
```

Y ahora ya podemos usarla:

```
template< int > double var;

template< > double var< 1 > = 2332.243;
template< > double var< 2 > = 12.23;

int main( ) {
    std::cout << var< 1 > << std::endl;
    std::cout << var< 2 > << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Las plantillas pueden ser abrumadoramente complicadas si no se entiende cómo funcionan. Como su nombre indica, son una plantilla para generar otra cosa, imagina que son como un tampón de tinta:

---

[image]

---

La "*instancia*" no existe hasta que estampas el tampón sobre un papel y para instanciar necesitas saber qué instanciar, ese "**qué instanciar**" son los parámetros plantilla.

Los parámetros plantilla, igual que otros constructos de C++ pueden ser definidos y usados, e igual que otros constructos se definen con dos palabras: `definidor nombre`; si sólo usas el `nombre` no estás definiendo nada estás **usando**. Aclarado eso veamos tu variable plantilla:

```
template <int T>
//        ^^^^^ <--- Definición de parámetro plantilla
double var<T>;
//         ^ <--- Uso de parámetro plantilla
```

En la definición de tu variable plantilla estás definiendo un parámetro a la vez que lo usas. No puedes comerte el pastel a la vez que lo horneas, seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
template <int T>
//        ^^^^^ <--- Definición de parámetro plantilla
double var;
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5NDsIgEEb3nGISN7qwtdRVwZ7CCyCQSkKh4cfEGM@OQKoLdRaTb15evgxflj3XzEwpbZThOgoJVFkfnGTziFCQ86JZKNAEOI9I2HjREm7MEYRQgTNTZrt7IMhTV9tya3JDvNviKeZB5ZsZnmM1MqXdCCfocd/gY08@FBfa4QavbC28sslC9Bbye/q3zwcxDNzGAJS@y3OqWBqhyX8Lf1tVczJEZ@BA0DOlFw)</kbd>.